# How to get OS version as std::string in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I made a console application and want to write OS name and version in the title. But the ways I tried did not work.

Firstly I tried a code I saw on Microsoft documents:
But it did not work and I got error called "C4996" (GetVersion() declared deprecated)

```
DWORD dwVersion = 0;
    DWORD dwMajorVersion = 0;
    DWORD dwMinorVersion = 0;
    DWORD dwBuild = 0;

    dwVersion = ::GetVersion();

    dwMajorVersion = (DWORD)(LOBYTE(LOWORD(dwVersion)));
    dwMinorVersion = (DWORD)(HIBYTE(LOWORD(dwVersion)));

    if (dwVersion < 0x80000000)
        dwBuild = (DWORD)(HIWORD(dwVersion));
```

After that I tried to use GetVersionExW() but it did not work either and deprecated too.

```
void GetOSVersion_Normal()
{
    OSVERSIONINFOEX versioninfo;
    versioninfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
    if (::GetVersionExW((LPOSVERSIONINFO)&versioninfo))
    {
        printf("MajorVersion : %d , MinorVersion : %d, ProductType : %d, ServicePack : %d.%d\n", versioninfo.dwMajorVersion, versioninfo.dwMinorVersion, versioninfo.wProductType, versioninfo.wServicePackMajor, versioninfo.wServicePackMinor);
        printf("\nMeaning of product type\n");
        printf("0 - UNKNOWN\n1 - VER_NT_WORKSTATION\n2 - VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER\n3 - VER_NT_SERVER\n");
    }
}
```

I tried to use #pragma to ignore warnings but it did not work.

Now Im sadly writing here :c

Comment: Thanks for the link. I disabled SDL check and it worked. Sorry for repeating same question. Im new on stackoverflow.